# Accumulating the sum of values ​of one cell in another cell

Tags: excel, vba, sum, accumulate

The question is:
How do I sum the input values ​​of a cell in another one?

For example:

1. I enter the value 5 in cell A1 and the cell A2 shows me 5;
2. I enter the value 3 in cell A1 and the cell A2 shows me 8;
3. I enter the value 4 in cell A1 and the cell A2 shows me 12.

Answer (score 1):

Place this in the worksheet module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim inpt As Range, otpt As Range

    Set inpt = [A1]: Set otpt = [A2]

    If Not Intersect(Target, inpt) Is Nothing Then
        otpt = otpt + inpt
        inpt = "" 'Option - Resets A1 after input
        inpt.Select 'Option - Returns selection to input cell
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```